# Migrating old JSP to Facelet (managed bean not instantiated)

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, apache-tomee

I use an old fashion JSP scriptlet code and I have decided to give Facelets a try and migrate my application. I already dislike some things (like the extra work of having to change some of the HTML5 tags that a designer gives me, close them, etc) but the benefits seem worth it. I am finding some problems in the migration, basically I am trying to define a `composite component` and pass over a `List<T extends BasicData>` to be displayed.

I am using `Netbeans 8.0.2`, `Apache Tomcat 8.0.3.0` (J2EE 7), `JDK 1.8`. I am reading [Java Server Faces - Introduction by example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484208390) to get help and examples.

**1)** I am not sure I have included the right dependencies in **Maven**, or if I included duplicated functionality with the libraries. Is this the minimum set? (considering I might use some JSTL)

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- This is the Mojarra Implementation of JSF -->
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-02</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**2)** Since **JSF 2.0**, I am not supposed to need the following fragment in the `web.xml`. However, when I omit it I don't get the JSF rendered and I only obtain the untreated XML. What am I doing wrong?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**3)** Now the main problem is that my bean doesn't seem to get instantiated. Everything renders fine except that the bean is passed is always `null`. In fact I can pass any data type (for example a `String` instead of a `List`) and it never complains (since whatever I pass is always `null` and Netbeans apparently does not detect it at compilation time).

**index.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/util"
                template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <util:visualisationList
            elementList="#{visualisationListController.elements}"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**visualisationListController.java**

```
    @Named(value = "visualisationListController")
    @Dependent
    public class VisualisationListController <T extends BasicData> implements Serializable {

        private List<T> elements;
        /**
         * Creates a new instance of visualisationList
         */
        public VisualisationListController() {
           // This is for testing, eventually I would like to get this information from a DB
            System.out.println("constructor");
            elements = new ArrayList<>();
            ComplexData cd = new ComplexData(); // ComplexData EXTENDS BasicData
            cd.setName("ELEMENT 1");
            elements.add((T)cd);
            cd = new ComplexData();
            cd.setName("ELEMENT 2");
            elements.add((T)cd);
        }

        public List<T> getElements() {
            return elements;
        }

        public void setElements(List<T> elements) {
            this.elements = elements;
        } 
    }
```

**visualisationList.xhtml**
(This renders, but the list is `null` so nothing is printed)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

        <!-- INTERFACE -->
        <cc:interface>
            <cc:attribute name="elementList" type="java.util.List" required="true" shortDescription="The list of objects to be displayed"/>
        </cc:interface>

        <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
        <cc:implementation>
                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.elementList}" var="element">
                            <li>
                                #{element.name}
                            </li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
        </cc:implementation>
    </html>
```

I never read I need a `beans.xml` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017979/bean-not-instantiated), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592048/jsf-2-managed-bean-does-not-get-instantiated) does not give me clues either. The bean is supposed to be automatically instantiated. To do some further testing, I have tried the first simple example from the aforementioned [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484208390) and my bean doesn't get instantiated either. I understand from the book text that the object should be automatically instantiated.

In case there is an error on the way I treat or create the `List`, I have also tried to use a less complex data (just a `String`), use `@SessionScoped` and remove the `c:forEach`, and it does not work either.

## **EDIT**

The problem is fixed thanks to (once again) `BalusC` pointer. I had to get information from different sources, so, for convenience, I have compiled the steps I took below. However, it is still not clear my question (1):
According to the [JSF info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) page, I only need to include one Maven dependency. But when doing so, I get the following error message:

```
An Error Occurred:

Could not get component metadata for visualisationList.xhtml. Did you forget to specify <composite:interface>?

viewId=/index.xhtml
location= ...
```

I have tried several things, including steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567789/javaserver-faces-2-2-composite-component-rendered-with-enclosing-html-ht), unsuccessfully. If I include certain libraries I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535)
```

The only thing that worked for me, although I am not sure why, is to include the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

(Together with the javaee-web-api 6.0 of course)

Only then, I get the result I was expecting from the beginning. However, I don't understand why this dependency has to be included, if TomEE was suppossed to provide it all. Also, I am not sure it means I will use v.2.2 when I have read that EE 6 should only run up to 2.1. Finally, I had to create a `beans.xml` for this to work, and I am not sure why - Is this only for JSF version <= 2.1?

---

### STEPS I TOOK TO CHANGE TOMCAT TO TOMEE ON NETBEANS

1. Download TomEE. Install and configure it in Netbeans servers section. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat))
2. Edit TomEE server.xml and changed all ports to avoid collision with my old Tomcat.
3. In server.xml, remove the `xpoweredBy` and `server` attributes from the connector:

   ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647156/tomee-starts-but-netbeans-gives-failed-to-start-error))
4. Then, in `bin/catalina.bat` change:

   ```
   :noJuliConfig
   set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"
   ...
   :noJuliManager
   set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   :noJuliConfig
   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
   ... 
   :noJuliManager
   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
   ```

   ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter))
5. Then right click on project - Properties - Run. Change server to TomEE and Java EE version to "Java EE 6 Web" (since the current version of TomEE only accepts JEE 1.6). Dependencies in `pom.xml` have to be changed accordingly, to version 6:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax</groupId>
       <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
       <version>6.0</version> <!-- 7.0 (JSF 2.2) or 6.0 (JSF 2.0/2.1) -->
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ....
   <artifactItem>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </artifactItem>
   ```

   ....

Now TomEE should work and run the application from Netbeans.

---

Comment: Another related food: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable (you would have faced this problem when submitting a form).

Comment: Many thanks for this! I have installed TomEE but it only supports JEE6 so when I use the dependency for "javaee-web-api" version "6.0" I get all sort of EE packages not found (ServletException, @Dependent...) - I followed http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. I thought TomEE already shipped with all that stuff... Am I doing something wrong?